# Checking input to a Powershell function

Tags: powershell

I've created a Powershell function that takes in a string.  I'm trying to validate that the char count of a string param is over 4, however whenever I check the param, the count is always 1.

Why is this so?

```
function DeleteSitesWithPrefix($prefix){

    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($prefix)){
        Write-Host "Please provide the name of the csv file to use"
        return
    }

    if([string]::$prefix.Length -lt 4){
        Write-Host "Please provide a prefix of 4 or more digits"
        return
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `if ($prefix.Length -lt 4) {...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[string]::` means calling a static method of string, but `$prefix.Length` is not such a method.

this will work:

```
if($prefix.Length -lt 4){
    Write-Host "Please provide a prefix of 4 or more digits"
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider rewriting your function using [validation attributes](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/08/09/powershell-scripting-validation.aspx):

```
function DeleteSitesWithPrefix
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.Length -ge 4})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Prefix
    )

    # Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()` is redundant, since null/empty values have a (string) length of 0.